# Not able to display rest api response from spring boot project to angular UI dashboard in localhost tomcat server

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, rest, tomcat

I've developed a basic CRUD application using Angular and Spring Boot. After deploying the UI's dist folder and the WAR file onto the local Tomcat server, I encountered a 404 not found issue when attempting to load the UI on localhost. Specifically, when I clicked on the UI to retrieve a list of friends from the backend, the expected response was not received, leading to the 404 error.

```
app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [

  {path:'home', component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'friends', component:FriendComponent},
  {path:'',component:HomeComponent}
  
];

friend.component.ts
getFriends(){
    this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/friendsapi/friends').subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.friends = response;
      }
    );

index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FriendsUI</title>
  <base href="/friends-ui">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

code link
[Github](https://github.com/kakollunareshkumar/FriendsCrud)
when I click on friends it should fetch list of friends as a response and display in UI.
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia9Ao.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxdno.png)